# PHP MYSQL CONCERN: Cannot fetch database information using $resultDetails->fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, database, conditional-statements

I cannot figure out why I can't access my WHILE clause inside my IF statement. I was just trying to fetch information from my database. I successfully connected to my DB for I got the echo statement just under my if statement. please help. I have been stuck for a long time

```
<?php
    require './db.php';
    $sqlDetails = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE created >= '{$_SESSION["time"]}' ORDER BY created asc";


    if($resultDetails = $conn->query($sqlDetails)) {
        echo "success entry to db";
        while($row = $resultDetails->fetch_assoc())  {
            echo "success fetch to db";

            echo "<script>console.log('insideWhile!!')</script>";

            $chatName = $row['username'];
            $chatMessage = $row['messages'];
            $chatfrom = $row['cfrom'];
            $chatTime = $row['created'];
            $chatId = $row['cid'];

            $sample .= '<tr>
            <th scope="row">'.$chatName.'</th>
            <td>'.$chatMessage.'</td>
            <td>'.$chatTime.'</td>
            </tr>';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   }

    $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Inside your if statement, if you var_dump($resultDetails) what is the result?

Comment: i tried and this is what i got:

success entry to dbobject(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }

wait...

Comment: If you run your SQL query in the database, are there results? Obviously replace the variable with the actual value (var_dump the variable so you get an accurate result).

Comment: i will try that right now. self learning and new here so i appreciate your response! Thank you

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: issue was my query $sqlDetails were not generating any row at all because there is zero result on that query. thats why my while statement is false to begin with. var_dump was very useful. thank you.   i will mark this as solved now i just don't know how. will research. This is my 1st stack overflow post. THANKYOU!

Comment: I'll add an answer for you to mark as resolved.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: i will! just 2 weeks into PHP and will learn that for sure. Thank you Dharman!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable in your SQL query doesn't contain the information you expect.

```
echo $sqlDetails;
```

You'll see that `$_SESSION["time"]` isn't correct.